# run perl script from another webpage

Tags: perl, https, http-status-codes

I need to run a perl script from another www page without causing warning for non-secure content.
I have SSL https secured www page: https://www.whatever.com in which index.htm has a line:

```
<img src="http://www.otherpage.com/myperl.pl?param1=hello">
```

The myperl.pl is a simple log counter - it is not loading anything. On the www.otherpage.com it just creates a log file. The www.otherpage.com has no SSl certifcate but www.whatever.com has.

How do I run the script so that the "padlock" icon stays green?

Comment: How much control do you have over www.otherpage.com, can you set it up to allow https requests?

Comment: I have full control over the www.otherpage.com. The otherpage has no HTTPS/SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Lets Encrypt to get valid SSL certificates for both domains.

You should look into CORS, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing